# Android Databinding in Sub-module

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin, android-databinding, android-studio-3.0

I have an application module, let's say "Test". The "Test" module depends on a sub-module B. Both enable databinding. In library module B, I create a simple activity using databinding, its purpose is for reusability, for example: I can create a base Login screen and use it in many apps later. Below is sample code in Package B.

```
package com.test.packageb

      open class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        }
    }
```

and then in "Test" module, I can just simply inherit MainActivity class to do customize things, like this:

```
class MainActivity1 : MainActivity(){

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    fun doSomething(){
        binding.rootLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary)
    }
}
```

However, when I try to run "Test" application, I got this error

> Error:(17, 9) Cannot access class
>    'com.test.packageb.databinding.ActivityMainBinding'. Check your module
>    classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
>   Error:(17, 17)
>    Unresolved reference: rootLayout

What did I miss? Is there anything else need to be implemented?

**Test app build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.testapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    dataBinding{
        enabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {

        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.0-beta4'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation project(':packageb')
}
```

**Package B build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    dataBinding{
        enabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.0-beta4'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: put you gradle code for help to see.

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel: I've added gradle files of both modules. Thanks.

Comment: https://blog.mindorks.com/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa check link

Comment: I've tried both "implementation" and "api" to Package B. Doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that you've created an activity_main.xml in your application as well as the module? Those layouts would conflict and it could be that the generated Binding is confused by the merged resources.

Comment: @GeorgeMount: Thanks for your reply, I did have that thought already. However, as I stated in the question, its purpose is for reusability, so there won't be 2 activities or 2 layouts whatsoever, just did a double check to make sure of that.

Comment: Are there any other warnings or errors? If you have any error in your code, data binding barfs and doesn't generate any code, causing errors like this.

Comment: @GeorgeMount: everything compiles just fine, in fact, the only error I got is stated in the question. I also notice that there're 2 binding classes generated (1 in Package B build folder, the other one in Test build folder), don't know if it was the problem.

Comment: Is your test module for the application or for the library module?

Comment: @GeorgeMount: Test module is the application. The one which generates APK file and run on devices. Package B is the library

Comment: This is probably of no help, but just to confirm you're not daydreaming. I'm having the same issue - I have a fragment with databinding inside a library. As soon as I'm trying to extend it in the top level app (not even adding any code, literally just typing ClassB extends ClassA{}), the build fails with "Cannot access <GeneratedBinding>". Been scratching my head for hours..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the issue is relevant to you but I managed to find some kind of the solution.

To make it work base class should have generic

```
class A<BINDING extends ViewDataBinding> {
    protected ABinding binding;

    void init(){
        binding = (ABinding) DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.a);
    }
}
```

and pass the same binding to the child class from the submodule

```
class B<ABinding> {
    // you can use instance in this class
}
```

The main problem here that you can't drastically change the UI, only hiding existing elements or add new at runtime. But I suppose in such case easier create a totally new class.